# Determining Device Sizes and Dimensions in Web Development and Mobile Emulation

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools, screen-size, mobile-emulator

I am currently working on a web development project and I am looking for a way to determine the sizes of various devices used for web browsing. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how the dimensions are determined in the mobile emulator mode within the developer tools of browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

For example, I have an LG K10 mobile phone with a screen size of 5.3 inches and a resolution of 1280x720 pixels. If I add this size directly to the device list, it appears significantly larger. Therefore, I have been using the "debug on mobile" feature (chrome://inspect/#devices), connecting the mobile phone to my computer and taking measurements. I found that the size is 360x540 pixels, which appears accurate as it matches what I see on the actual device.

My question is, how can I measure the dimensions of other mobile devices in a similar manner? I would like to determine the accurate dimensions of various mobile devices for testing purposes.

Thank you for your assistance and guidance.